# I need a button for a Tampermonkey script

Tags: html, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I need a button that runs these two codes alternately:

`document.querySelector('.top-left').style.width = '340px'`

`document.querySelector('.top-left').style.width = '0px'`

Clicking once executes one, clicking again executes the other!

It is a button to hide a column on the page.

Can anybody help me?
I'm not getting.
I created the button but I can't add that function to it!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow fealBrunnoS ! It really helps to provide a minimal reproducible example:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

```
<button onclick="myFunction">Click me</button>
const myFunction = (event)=> {
  const elm= document.querySelector('.top-left');
  if(elm.style.width==="340px")
    elm.style.width = '0px';
  else
    elm.style.width = '340px'
};
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is [Toggle Class](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_class.asp)

Your button would look something like this

```
<button id="button-show-hide">Show/Hide</button>

let el = document.querySelector('.top-left')
let button = document.getElementById('button-show-hide')

button.addEventListener('click',showHide)

function showHide(){
   el.classList.toggle('hide')
}
```

and the CSS

```
.top-left .hide {
  width: 0px;
}
```